# QGIS: Custom formatting coordinate grid to reduce number of decimals

Tags: qgis, coordinates, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules, qgis-custom-function

I am making a coordinate grid system of a map I have made, but now I would like to reduce the number of decimals of the seconds (of the latitude and longitude).

So instead of 36°54'0.000"E -> 36°54'0"E

[image]

I think this is done using the custom function: "round", but I do not know which formula I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll further down the grid properties panel you come to `Coordinate Precision` reducing the `3` to `0` with give the result you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! I'm just a beginner in QGIS and I did not see this option. Thank you :)

Comment: if this answer helped please up vote it and / or accept it. The [tour] provides more detail on how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `round` in particular but just read again the expression manual for `to_dms` (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-dms).

For x coordinates, replace the `36.90` with your `x` column name

```
with_variable('your_coord', 36.90, 
  if (
    @your_coord < 0,
    to_dms(@your_coord, 'x', 0) || 'W',
    to_dms(@your_coord, 'x', 0) || 'E'
  )
)
```

For y coordinates, replace the `18.90` with your `y` column name

```
with_variable('your_coord', 18.90, 
  if (
    @your_coord < 0,
    to_dms(@your_coord, 'y', 0) || 'S',
    to_dms(@your_coord, 'y', 0) || 'N'
  )
)
```

PS: There is an option `aligned` in `to_dms` but it does not fit exacty your requirements, hence the "bastard" version above

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!